# How to Get IP Addresses of Computers In Active Directory Domain

Tags: ip, active-directory

I'm not even sure if this is the proper approach but I have a number of computers on our school network (domain) that I need to report the IP addresses for.  All of these computers are contained in a single orgizational unit in the domain.

Is there a way to use Active Directory to get the IP addresses for each of the machines?  I looked in the Attribute Editor in ADUC but didn't see this field.  However, I did see the dNSHostName.  Maybe there is a way to resolve that to an IP address in code somehow?

Is there a much easier way to accomplish something like this that I'm just missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DNS Manager should have a list of computer names and what IP address they have been assigned.

Comment: +1: DNS is a better bet than DHCP for this kind of thing. AD maintains the DNS for various reasons, and the name in the AD will be the same as the computer names in the OU. Additionally, if you have more than one subnet, they'll still all be in 1 DNS group, rather than broken out by subnet.

Answer (score 2):

How to use PowerShell to Get the IP Address from the Computer object in AD.

```
$ComputerName = "Computer01"

(Get-ADComputer $ComputerName -Properties IPv4Address).IPv4Address
```

Answer (score 1):

Through ADUC, I'm not sure you can get an IP from a hostname. You could look in the DHCP snap-in (if that's whats handing out addresses), check the DNS manager on the server or use a tool like [Angy IP Scanner](http://www.angryip.org/w/Download)

Comment: AngryIPScanner is a lovely little tool, have used it for years, though beware it shows as a false positive with some Anti-virus software

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge there is no way to achieve what you require through active directory. You may be able to look in your servers DNS to find both the IP's and Hostnames to export to a spreadsheet or other format.

You could also use an IP scanner such as angryIP scanner.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ping the computer name, the IP address will display in the results